# Samsung 970 EVO NVMe only using 2x PCIe gen3 lanes

Tags: nvme, m.2

Today I bought a Samsung 970 EVO 500gb NVMe drive, installed it and everything went smooth. Drive showed up, and works.

However, when I went to benchmark it, I saw it was only pulling about half of the speeds that it should be capable off. So I downloaded and installed the "Samsung Magician" software, which shows that only 2 PCIe lanes are being used.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULnrq.png

Meanwhile my motherboard, a Z170A MSI Krait Gaming 3x, says it supports M.2 NVMe over PCIe Gen3 x4
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170A-KRAIT-GAMING-3X/Specification

In addition to the 970 EVO, I have 2 additional drives connected via SATA 3 (6Gb/s), 1x Intel SSD 330 series and 1x Samsung HD753LJ.

I have made sure I have the latest drivers for the 970 EVO as well as my MB being flashed with the latest BIOS version.

I've rummaged through various BIOS settings, but can't find anything that could be at fault.

Any ideas?

Side note:
The other additional 2 drives are plugged into Sata3 and Sata4.

Tenchmark from Samsung Magician, which clearly shows only about half speeds of what it should be pulling.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHveS.png

Comment: Do you have any other PCIe devices attached to your PC? Have you reseated the SSD on the motherboard?

Comment: @SamForbis I have a GPU in the topmost PCIe x16 slot, and I have reseated it, no dice